# AutowiringFailedException when overriding FOSUserBundle registration form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

*(Using Symfony 3 on WampServer on Windows 10)*

I am trying to extends FOSBundle's user form according following instructions from https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/fosuserbundle/customize-forms
(I chose the option to "override" so I skipped the "extend" part using `getParent()`)

I get

```
**AutowiringFailedException**
Cannot autowire service "app.form.registration": argument "$class" of method "AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType::__construct()" must have a type-hint or be given a value explicitly.
```

Some configuration:
*..\Appbundle\Form\RegistrationFormType.php*

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use FOS\UserBundle\Util\LegacyFormHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType'), array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('plainPassword', LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType'), array(
                'type' => LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType'),
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            ))
            ->add('number')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
            'csrf_token_id' => 'registration',
            // BC for SF < 2.8
            'intention' => 'registration',
        ));
    }

    // BC for SF < 3.0
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }
}
```

*Custom user class*

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`fasuser`")
*/
class FasUser extends BaseUser
{
    /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $Number;

    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->Number;
    }
    public function setNumber(string $number)
    {
        $this->Number = $number;
    }

}
```

*In services.yml:*

```
(...)
    app.form.registration:
        class: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

*In config.yml:*

```
(...)
fos_user:
    (...)
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `__constructor` from `RegistrationFormType`:

And change your `data_class`:

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
      ......
      'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User', //Your user Entity class
      ......
```

Answer (score 4):

I realize that there is already an accepted answer but it involves refactoring the form type class and moving the constructor arguments to the options array.  Which can be a bit of a pain since it means you have to set the option value from wherever the form is created.

The basic problem is that autowire cannot possibly figure out the desired value of a string parameter.  Hence the error message concerning $class.

Fortunately you can pass $class from your service definition.

```
// services.yml
AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType:
    tags: [form.type]
    arguments: {$class: 'AppBundle\Entity\User'}
```

Should do the trick.  Notice also a slightly more condensed version of specifying the tag.

One final note is that autowire can still figure out additional object constructor arguments.  So the above service definition would also work for:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, string $class)
```

Kind of fun to play around though I still have some concerns about autowire with respect to long term maintenance.

One more bit of refinement. Symfony can now automatically wire tags based on what the service implements.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#autoconfiguring-tags So any class that implements FormTypeInterface is automatically tagged with form.type

The service definition can now be reduced to:

```
AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType:
    $class: 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
```

Keeping track of everything being configured can be challenging.  This command can help troubleshoot:

```
php bin/console debug:container "AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType"
```

I'm guessing that Harry Potter is secretly a member of the Symfony development team.  Or maybe Lucius Malfoy.

Answer (score 0):

My solution : override parent constructor

```
namespace App\AppBundle\Form\Type\Admin;

use App\AppBundle\Entity\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ChangePasswordFormType as BaseType;

class ChangePasswordFormType extends BaseType
{
    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct(User $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($class);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'sonata_user_admin_change_password';
    }
}
```